# iPadアプリのiPad Pro 10.5インチへの画像表示の対応

Tags: ios

今、開発中のiPadアプリのiPad Pro対応をしているのですが、

・9.7インチモデル
・10.5インチモデル
・12.7インチモデル

に対応させないといけないのですが、
例えば、hogehoge.pngって画像がありまして、
これを表示させたい場合、

9.7インチモデルでは、hogehoge.pngファイルが表示されます。
12.7インチモデルでは、hogehoge@2x.pngファイルが表示されます。

困ったのは、10.5モデルで、このモデルの場合も
12.7インチモデルと同じ、hogehoge@2x.pngが
表示されてしまいます。

10.5インチモデルでは、10.5インチ用のhogehoge.pngを
表示したいのですが、どうすれば宜しいでしょうか。
hogehoge@1.5x.png みたいな対応になるのでしょうか。

分かる方おられましたら、
ご教授お願い出来ますでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 何に対する「対応」なのかが分からないので、例えばネイティブアプリの開発であるならそうと分かるよう、もう少し具体的な情報を追記してもらった方がアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。もう少し具体的な情報を追記しようと思います。

Comment: ファイル名に@2x付きの画像は、「2倍Retinaディスプレイ用の画像ですよ」と指定していることになります。iPad Proであれば、現在販売されているものはすべて2倍Retinaのはずなので、9.7インチモデルであっても@2xの画像が使われるはずです。モデルによって切り替わるものではなかったはずです。

Comment: 9.7インチモデルで確認してみたのですが、
ご指摘の通り、@2xの画像が表示されました。
今まで誤解しておりました。

モデルによって表示される画像を切替えたかったのですが、
その場合は、プログラムで制御しないとダメそうですね。

Answer (score 1):

それぞれのメディアクエリの値が以下になるようです。

```
機種　端末解像度(横×縦)　実質解像度(横×縦)　画素(ppi)　デバイスピクセル比
12.7　2,048px×2,732px　　1,024px×1,366px　　264 ppi　　2.0
10.5　1,668px×2,224px　　  834px×1,112px　　264 ppi　　2.0
 9.7　1,536px×2,048px　　  768px×1,024px　　264 ppi　　2.0
```

CSS/srcsetのブレイクポイント値が9.7インチの768px×1,024pxになっているのでしょう。
10.5インチの834px×1,112pxに変更するか、いっそ3種類に分けるとかすれば良いのでは無いでしょうか。

参考サイト
[iPad Proの解像度はいくら？ディスプレイを徹底検証！](https://www.earlyteches.com/2017/07/ipad-pro-resolution/)
[10.5インチiPad Proのメディアクエリは、縦 834 px 横 1112 px CSSテクニック](https://mono96.jp/for_blogger/31512/)
[CSS3: 最新 Bootstrap 対応 iOS メディアクエリのテンプレート](http://www.sirochro.com/note/css3-bs-ios-mediaquery-template/)

[srcset属性について](https://qiita.com/C058/items/643a9ff2d23dfe3a0b37)
[メディアクエリの書き方「レスポンシブwebデザイン導入方法」](https://kasegood.net/media-queries)
[レスポンシブのブレイクポイントを設定する前に知っておくべきこと](https://deaimobi.com/breakpoint/)

---

第三世代機の記事があったので追記：実質解像度とデバイスピクセル比は推測した値

```
機種　端末解像度(横×縦)　実質解像度(横×縦)　画素(ppi)　デバイスピクセル比
12.9　2,048px×2,732px　　1,024px×1,366px　　264 ppi　　2.0
11.0　1,668px×2,388px　　  834px×1,194px　　264 ppi　　2.0
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
３種類に分ける方向で検討したいと思います。